# How to convert 2.3449 to Decimal

Tags: c#, casting, decimal

I am trying to convert 2.3449 to Decimal but It converts like 23449,0

I am converting it like below

```
string temp = "2.3449";
decimal value_ = Convert.ToDecimal(temp);
```

if I replace the DOT with COLON, it converts it perfectly. But, I dont want to Replace the DOT with COLON in string. What is the good way of converting without replacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your culture treats `.` as the thousands separator, rather than decimal separator.

You can always use a specific culture:

```
var val = decimal.Parse(temp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The same goes for `ToString` - if you want to print the number with `.` as the decimal separator, just use the appropriate culture. The local culture (the default) is usually the best bet for anything user-facing, though. Invariant culture is perfect for persistence :)